# PHP error message on init.php

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm using 000webhost.com and uploaded all of my coding in it. But then this error shows up when I try open up the website:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/a4350293/public_html/core/init.php on line 25

This is the line on init.php:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Can anyone tell me where my error is? Can't seem to find it.
Thanks, all help appreciated.
This is the link to my website: http://educationexperts.host56.com/

Comment: Is your webhost running at least php 5.3? If not, I suggest finding a new host. Any web host that allows new sites to use less than php 5.3 should be condemned.

Comment: check the php version, because the closure needs php5.3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look and it appears that "000webhost.com" runs PHP 5.2.

[Reference](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/comments-suggestions/22903-upgrade-php-5-2-x-5-3-x-12.html)

This is not good because PHP 5.2 is no longer supported. You must find a web host that supports a later version of PHP. Preferably 5.4 as 5.3 has also reached it's EOL (end of life).

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the hosting providers features

http://www.000webhost.com/free-php-hosting

Supports only PHP 5 and like others commented earlier, you will need 5.3.